# Asus ROG GL553VW Keyboard Backlight, Fan Control and Keyboard Shortcuts not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, asus

Does anyone know how to setup the keyboard backlight control, fan control and screen brightness keyboard shortcut on the Asus ROG GL553VW for Ubuntu 20.04LTS? I have searched everywhere and I could not find a working solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Issue solved by rebuilding the lastest stable Linux Kernel and changing the file drivers/hid/hid-ids.h in the Linux kernel with the following changes (accoding to apeelme at https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=194557):

-#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x1837

+#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ASUSTEK_ROG_KEYBOARD2 0x8176